# How do I REbuild OpenSuse kernels?

Tags: linux, kernel, opensuse, rebuild, linux-kernel

I am trying to install some patches and drivers needed for a wifi card, but im getting an error that says: "build your kernel with CONFIG_LIBIPW=m."

How can I recompile the kernel to add that?

And can I do it without having to download a new kernel package? (i mean recompiling the existing kernels)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but the chances of bricking your system are not small. So be warned.

1. Install the `kernel-source` package

   1. `rug in kernel-source`
   2. Or open Yast -> Software Management. Install the 'kernel source' package.
2. Open a command-prompt as root
3. CD to /usr/src/linux
4. `cp /proc/config.gz`
5. `gunzip config.gz`
6. `cp config .config`
7. Open .config in editor-of-choice
8. Look for the CONFIG_LIBIPW line

**Note**: You may find that it is ALREADY set to "m". In that case, *stop now* as something else is your problem.

1. Change it from `n` to `m`
2. Save .config
3. `make prepare`
4. `make oldconfig`
5. `make M=/drivers/net/`
6. `make install`
7. reboot

Comment: I dont have any /usr/src/linux, I do have /usr/src/linux-KERNELVERSION-obj/, but there I dont see all the usual folders+files of /usr/src/linux, I only see two folders (i386 & i586) and inside those folders there are only 2 files, im using OpenSuse 10.3 (logged as root).

Comment: Oh, 10.3. That's pretty old. I'll what I can remember.

Answer (score 1):

rug is long gone. The proper way is:

1. grab some sources. There are many ways, such as pulling from the SUSE kernel git tree, but that's a download of course. `zypper in kernel-source`, provided that you are ok with that it may download that somewhere.
2. `rsync -HPSav /usr/src/linux-2.the version you chose/ ~/linux/`
3. go into the directory and use `make cloneconfig`/menuconfig/etc. Do not run the commands in /usr/src/ or root, as that can break KMP building for that kernel. `make prepare` is redundant, as is oldconfig when menuconfig/etc has already been run.
4. `make M=/drivers/net` is no sufficient, because `System.map` needs to exist first. Just run `make`, or incomplete objects may be manufactured.
5. `make install` seems to still fiddle around with LILO, almost nobody uses this make target. Copy the stuff by hand.